# Set where function has high values is small

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on a set $A$, and let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Given $\epsilon>0$, is it true that we can find $n$ such that $\mu\{|f(x)|>n\}<\epsilon$?

Intuitively it looks like it should be true (just choose $n$ large enough so that most of the values of $f$ is below $n$), but how can we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A_n = \{ x : \lvert f(x)\rvert >n\}$. You have $A_n \supset A_{n+1}$ and

$$\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty A_n = \varnothing.$$

The continuity of the measure - since $\mu(A) < \infty$ - now shows $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n) = 0$.